# get vscode python error when run pyspark program using vs code

Tags: python, pyspark, visual-studio-code

I run my pyspark program in vscode, and get error:
`PicklingError: Could not serialize object: ImportError: No module named visualstudio_py_debugger` .
I suppose it has something to do with my vscode setting?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your code is trying to pickle the debugger itself. Do make sure you are running the debugger using the PySpark configuration.